# If matlab uses all cores of my laptop or not

Tags: linux, matlab

When running a code in MatLab, how can I recognize if it uses all 5 cores my laptop contains or not? I'm using Linux Mint.

```
Should I type some thing in terminal?
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you number of workers available:

```
myCluster = parcluster('local');
myCluster.NumWorkers
```

To get number of workers working, use:

```
n = numlabs
```